# pass variable value to make using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to do something like

```
cmake -DUSE_FILES_FOR_INPUT=ON ..
```

and then get `make` to compile my files with `-DUSE_FILES_FOR_INPUT=ON`. But I don't get the `=ON` value. It seems that it should be written to a flags.make file, but it isn't:

```
$ grep USE_FILES_FOR_INPUT source/CMakeFiles/myprogram.dir/flags.make
CXX_DEFINES = -DUSE_FILES_FOR_INPUT
```

If I manually change that file with `-DUSE_FILES_FOR_INPUT=ON` then everything works fine.
How can I get cmake to add the value in `flags.make`?

A different approach to what I need to do: the variable I am using has type BOOL, so it would be good enough to get

`CXX_DEFINES = -DUSE_FILES_FOR_INPUT` when I do `cmake -DUSE_FILES_FOR_INPUT=ON ..`
and
`CXX_DEFINES =` when I do `cmake -DUSE_FILES_FOR_INPUT=OFF ..`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a small demonstration,

```
// demo.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
#ifdef USE_FILES_FOR_INPUT
    cout << "Using files.." << endl;
#else
    cout << "Not using files.." << endl;
#endif


    return 0;
}
```

The CMakeLists.txt,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

add_executable(demo demo.cpp)

if (USE_FILES_FOR_INPUT)
    add_definitions(-DUSE_FILES_FOR_INPUT)
endif()
```

And a sample output,

```
baris$ cmake . && make && ./demo
<...>
Not using files..

baris$ cmake -DUSE_FILES_FOR_INPUT=ON . && make && ./demo
<...>
Using files..
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [configure_file documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/configure_file.html). They show an example using the special cmake construct `#cmakedefine`. This may be a little more work than Baris describes, but I prefer using `configure_file` and `#cmakedefine` to get cmake settings into C++ code.

Here is the complete [example](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/configure_file.html#example):

---

Consider a source tree containing a foo.h.in file:

```
#cmakedefine FOO_ENABLE
#cmakedefine FOO_STRING "@FOO_STRING@"
```

An adjacent `CMakeLists.txt` may use configure_file to configure the header:

```
option(FOO_ENABLE "Enable Foo" ON)
if(FOO_ENABLE)
  set(FOO_STRING "foo")
endif()
configure_file(foo.h.in foo.h @ONLY)
```

This creates a `foo.h` in the build directory corresponding to this source directory. If the `FOO_ENABLE` option is on, the configured file will contain:

```
#define FOO_ENABLE
#define FOO_STRING "foo"
```

Otherwise it will contain:

```
/* #undef FOO_ENABLE */
/* #undef FOO_STRING */
```

One may then use the `include_directories()` command to specify the output directory as an include directory:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

so that sources may include the header as `#include <foo.h>`.